# MIDAS regression where m is not an integer

Tags: time-series

MIDAS regression seems to be straightforward when the number of observations in the  high-frequency series is a multiple "m" of the number of observations in the low-frequency series, where $m \in \mathbb{N}$ (e.g. LF data are annual and HF data are monthly, or quarterly and monthly). However, what if the low frequency data are monthly and the high frequency data are weekly, so that $m$ is not an integer. Any thoughts? Can MIDAS still be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lag function used in MIDAS is often a beta function, which is defined for non-integer arguments. I would suspect that it would fairly easy to make the necessary adjustments. For that matter, the Almon lag is designed to handle a variety of lags, with only a maximum lag specification required. I don't see anything blocking your way forward.